# Log4j: How to filter by class in a separate file

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

I'm getting odd results while making changes to an existing config:

**Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" verbose="true" dest="err" name="RdmCoreLogProperties">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseFilename">$${env:SOME_VAR}/$${sys:processName}_$${sys:instanceNumber}_$${env:SOME_VAR2}.log</Property>
        <Property name="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{1.} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseFilename}" filePattern="${baseFilename}.%02i" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="99"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <!--My new file-->
        <File name="Filtered" fileName="${baseFilename}_FILTERED.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!--Already existing loggers-->
        <Logger name="1AB" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="1AB.message" level="trace"/>
        <Logger name="2AB" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="2AB.message" level="trace"/>
        <!--Already existing loggers-->


        <!--My new Logger-->
        <Logger name="com.package.MyClass">
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Filtered"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Filtered"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**"Filtered" log file** (see how the lines of interest are now duplicated!)

```
bla bla bla not interesting text...
16:36:30.963 [XXX] INFO  com.package.MyClass - important and unique text
16:36:30.963 [XXX] INFO  com.package.MyClass - important and unique text
bla bla bla more boring and not interesting text...
```

**Original log file** (the file remains untouched, and this is actually ok)

```
bla bla bla not interesting text...
16:36:30.963 [XXX] INFO  com.package.MyClass - important and unique text
bla bla bla more boring and not interesting text...
```

**Desired filtered log file**

```
16:36:30.963 [XXX] INFO  com.package.MyClass - important and unique text
```

Note 1: If i add additivity="false" to the new logger, i get this:

**"Filtered" log file** (now the log is equal to the original log file)

```
bla bla bla not interesting text...
16:36:30.963 [XXX] INFO  com.package.MyClass - important and unique text
bla bla bla more boring and not interesting text...
```

**Original log file**

```
bla bla bla not interesting text...
bla bla bla more boring and not interesting text...
```

Note 2: If i change the logger name to a non-existing class, the original and the new log file are equal.

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake: i needed to remove the appender from the root, so it does not inherits from it.

```
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `additivity="false"` to your logger. In this case:

```
    <Logger name="com.package.MyClass" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Filtered"/>
    </Logger>
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: You are missing a `"` after the `false` in first line

Comment: Fixed. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have edited my question with the results